# Slicing data by conditional selection of multiple columns in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set with NA in **item_weight**. There is another attribute called **item_type**, which has levels like dairy, kitchen, household etc.

I have used `cbind()` to get a few values.

```
         x        y                      
     [1,] "9.3"    "Dairy"                `
     [2,] "5.92"   "Soft Drinks"          
     [3,] "17.5"   "Meat"                 
     [4,] "19.2"   "Fruits and Vegetables"
     [5,] "8.93"   "Household"            
     [6,] "10.395" "Baking Goods"         
     [7,] "13.65"  "Snack Foods"          
     [8,] NA       "Snack Foods"
```

I wanted to *select the NA's of item_weight* in such a way that the mean of item_weights *corresponding to different item_types* are replaced.

ex: the values of dairy item_type are replaced with NA's which correspond to Dairy Item_type only.

P.S.i have found the individual means of item_types using data.table package, I'm stuck with replacing NA's.
data.table:-

```
    library(data.table)
    dt<-data.table(train)
    dt[,mean(Item_Weight,na.rm = T),by=Item_Type]
```

output of data table:

```
    Item_Type       V1
    1:                 Dairy 13.42607
    2:           Soft Drinks 11.84746
    3:                  Meat 12.81734
```

Comment: please post your data.table code and its results, so it will be easier to understand the process

Comment: so, you have done `dt[.(mean = mean(x)), by = y]` to get the means right?

Comment: @mRcSchwering yup i did the dt to get individual item_type  means of item_weights

Comment: @Sathish here is the output of DT to find means of item_weights

Comment: Item_Type       V1
 1:                 Dairy 13.42607
 2:           Soft Drinks 11.84746
 3:                  Meat 12.81734
 4: Fruits and Vegetables 13.22477
 5:             Household 13.38474
 6:          Baking Goods 12.27711
 7:           Snack Foods 12.98788
 8:          Frozen Foods 12.86706
 9:             Breakfast 12.76820
10:    Health and Hygiene 13.14231
11:           Hard Drinks 11.40033
12:                Canned 12.30571
13:                Breads 11.34694
14:         Starchy Foods 13.69073
15:                Others 13.85328
16:               Seafood 12.55284`

Comment: please add it in your question

Comment: I think I would loop through the vector of means and then always replace item_weight with this mean if 1. item_weight is NA and 2. item_type is the same.